# Naming an undefined numer of variables

Tags: java, arrays

I've made an array of Strings and then I've split the String.

So in the array I've [time0, operator, time1, operator, time2 ...].

Now here is where I'm stuck, in my class Time I've the method to make a new Time of an String. So I've made a loop for resorting the array.

And my idea was to make a:

```
Time name1 = new Time(array[i]);


Time name2 = new Time(array[i])...;
```

But since I don't know how many new Times I've in each new operation...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: could you put some example. you can use `for-each` of java to iterate over your array.

Comment: use a list instead

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24725374/java-postfix-calculator-push-pop-method-with-a-string-array) might give you some other ideas i.e. to use a stack for your calculator. I guess only difference being operator meanings differing than normal arithmetic operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can't predict a number of variables that will be needed to save time values. But you know that every second element (`i`, `i+2`, `i+4`) is a time value and you are free to save them into an array, or a list:

```
Time[] times = new Time[array.length / 2 + 1];
// List<Time> times = new ArrayList<>(array.length / 2 + 1);

for (int i =0; i < array.length; i += 2) {
    times[i] = new Time(array[i]);
    // times.add(new Time(array[i]));
}
```